# Insert last id from one table into another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, **articles** and **logs**. When new record is inserted into the **articles** table the ID of that article should be inserted into the **logs** table after that... How this can be done using mysql/php? Can anyone please provide an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one very simple example

```
$query = "INSERT INTO article(article_title, article_body) VALUES('some title', 'some text')";
    mysql_query($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO logs(article_id, user_id) VALUES(" . mysql_insert_id() . ", 1)";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

After an insert query through PHP's `mysql_query()`, you can get the ID by calling the `mysql_insert_id()` function.  Then you can run your log insert query.

This could also be accomplished automatically if you created an insert trigger on the articles table.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could use

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID;
```

to retrieve the last inserted row's id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

More information [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/PHP/php.general/2007-02/msg00870.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a database trigger for this. so You need not to care every time you insert in article table. trigger will automatically get fired.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_article AFTER INSERT ON articles
     BEGIN
         insert into logs( article_id ) values ( scope_identity());
     END;
```